# How to prevent a youtube video from automatic displaying the next video after playing?

Tags: html, youtube

After I play a youtube video on my website using autoplay how сan I prevent it from displaying the Next videos? Here's my code:

```
<p>
<div class="w3-row w3-padding-0">
    <div id="topleftfadein"  class="w3-col s12 l12 m12 w3-margin-bottom animated fadeInLeft slower w3-white">
        <div class="videoWrapperOuter">
            <div id="yt1" class="videoWrapperInner">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TMEmv9uienU?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&controls=0"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't. It's 'part' of the video from youtube. You can't cut or remove that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `?rel=0` to the end of the video URL. Example: `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vXkQSiJG7fk?rel=0"`

Make sure the URL has `/embed/` instead of `/watch?`